# How to pass the table name through external properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I need to pass the `@Table` name from the config as per the environment. Here is what I tried:

```
public class CustomNamingStrategy extends SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy {

    //Making this field as static works but not the instance variable
    private static String tableName;

    //This is an instance method. Using this to set the static value does not seem to be a good practice. findbugs also complains on this.
    @Value("${my-app.prop.tableName}")
    public void setTableName(String tableName) {
        CustomNamingStrategy.tableName = tableName;
    }

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(
            Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context
    ) {
        if (TABLE_NAME.equals("PLACEHOLDER")) {
            System.out.println("table name is: " + CustomNamingStrategy.tableName);
            return Identifier.toIdentifier(CustomNamingStrategy.tableName);
        }
        return super.toPhysicalTableName(name,context);
    }
}
```

Also, set the physical naming strategy like this:
`properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", CustomNamingStrategy.class.getName());`

- Why does it work when I declare the tableName property as static but not as instance variable?
- What do I need to do to make this work without declaring it static? Is it even possible? When I try with instance variable the value is correctly logged in the `constructor` but the same value is null in the overridden method `toPhysicalTableName`

Comment: The only reason I can think of for `static` member to work and an instance member not to would be if Spring would be instancing multiple `CustomNamingStrategy`. Have you tried debugging to confirm that both calls (`setTableName` and `toPhysicalTableName`) are made on the same instance of `CustomNamingStrategy`?

Comment: Maybe I'm not following the point, why you simply can't put `@Value` annotation on top of the `private String tableName` - without making it static? You also need to make sure that your `CustomNamingStrategy` class is Spring a bean: annotated as a @Component or instantiated inside the @Configuration class via @Bean annotated method.

Comment: Thanks @skryvets for your response but I have tried that as well. The thing is table name gets initialized properly if we do that inside constructor or using `@Value` but those values are not available in the overridden method: `toPhysicalTableName`

Comment: Thanks @Anderson for checking it out. Both calls are being made on different instances.

Comment: @Jill have you solved the issue? if not using `@Scope("singleton")` on your component might do the trick (unless it might affect your application in some negative way from other usecases).

Comment: Its not yet solved. Even setting `Scope("singleton")` does not work. I am trying to solve this using inner class (non-static) where `CustomNamingStrategy` will be the inner class. But the problem is - now instantiation is failing with the error: NoSuchMethodException InnerClass.<init>()